# how to make a matrix from an archive .properties?

Tags: java, matrix, properties, archive

I need to create a matrix from an archive. The archive is .properties and already loaded. When read it has the form: 
`data.row0 = 3-9-0-1-10-1-0-9-0-4 
data.row1 = 1-1-5-1-8-1-5-1-1-1
data.row2 = 9-1-0-0-0-0-0-0-1-3`

Comment: suppose you share the code that you have tried so far

Comment: "already loaded" how?   In an array of `String`s? In a `java.util.Properties` object? In individual `String` variables?